# Moving common code between two implementations of interface

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, design-patterns

I have an interface called processor:

```
public interface Processor {
    MyResponse process(Request request, String id);
}
```

I have two implementations of this processor, one synchronous, the other asynchronous (both Spring Service classes):

This is Sync Version, completes the job and give a fully populated response:

```
@Service
public class SynchrnousProcess implements Processor {

    @Override
    public MyResponse process(Request request, String id) {
        Job job = getJob(request);
        JobParameters parameter = buildParams(request, id);
        JobExecution jobExecution = kickOfJob(job, request, parameter);
        return buildResponse(request, trackingId, jobExecution);
    }    
}
```

This is Async version, which adds requests to blocking queue:

```
@Service
public class AsyncProcess implements Processor {


     private BlockingQueue<Pair> requestQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100);

    @Override
    public MyResponse process(Request request, String id) {
     //add request to requestQueue 
    }    

    public void completeProcess() {
    //take data from queue and process
    log.info("start process !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(requestQueue)) {
        requestQueue.stream().forEach(pair -> {
            String trackingId = String.valueOf(pair.getFirst());

            FeedDto feedDto = (FeedDto) pair.getSecond();
            Request request = feedDto.getRequest();
            Job job = getJob(request);

            JobParameters parameter = getJobParameters(request, trackingId);
            JobExecution jobExecution = runJob(job, request, parameter);
    }
}
```

As you can see, `completeProcess()` takes data out of the queue and processes the job. Common code to do with getting job, building param is duplicated between synchronous run and async.

Another thread runs `completeProcess()` in background.

I want to achieve a clean design and move common code that are shared by the two interface implementations in one place. How can I achieve this for what I am trying to achieve? It will be really helpful to see an example of the design pattern to use in this case?

In Addition, any suggestion as to where the ExecutorService to process the queued requests should be initiated and how the threads to process these should be started will help a lot.

Comment: How does `AsyncProcess.process` return `MyResponse`? Given that Java doesn't have coroutines or async/await I would think this is impossible

Comment: it returns a response object made up of just a trackingId, random UUID, to the client, but that object doesnt have the result of the processing.Sync and Async process should return immediate, but with Async request queued, response retrieved later via another endpoint, the full complete one.

Comment: So if I get an object that implements the Processor interface and I don't know which implementation it is, I need to call the other end point just in case it's the asynchronous one?

Comment: the idea is I wire in interface reference in controller e.g. Processor processor; and as this is framework that gets injected as dependency to other microservice project, those other projects can configure which implementations they want to use. But the framework should support both. But not give two endpoints e.g. /process/sync and /process/async.

Answer (score 0):

You could design the interface as it has to perform async operations. For example:

```
public interface Callback() {
    void onResponse(MyResponse mr);
}

public void Processor {
    void process(Request request, String id, Callback callback);
}

@Service
public class SynchrnousProcess implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Request request, String id, Callback callback) {
        Job job = getJob(request);
        JobParameters parameter = buildParams(request, id);
        JobExecution jobExecution = kickOfJob(job, request, parameter);
        MyResponse r = buildResponse(request, trackingId, jobExecution);
        callback.onResponse(r);
    }    
}

@Service
public class AsyncProcess implements Processor {


     private BlockingQueue<Pair> requestQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100);

    @Override
    public void process(Request request, String id, Callback callback) {
     //add request and callback to requestQueue 
    }    

}
```

I don't know who will process the queue, but surely who will use Processor does not have to worry if the call is synchronous or not.

this is the most similar approach to the one you would use in C# with async await.
In C# you have to return a Task < MyResponse > even in the synchronous case. Then the consumer will always think that the call will be asynchronous.